# Background thread in Window_Loaded event threading error

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have to load a window and in `Window_Loaded` I have to load some variables and show it on Window.

```
private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{         
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
    {
        try
        {
            //code to download some variables which will show on UI of Window Loading
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
        }
    };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
    {

    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

But I am getting a threading exception. Is there any way to show the variables value on window from `DoWork` of `Backgroundworker`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should retrieve the data you need in the `DoWork` section, then assign it to `ea.Result`, which will make it available in the `RunWorkerCompleted` section.

In the `RunWorkerCompleted` section, you can access `ea.Result` again, casting the object back to whatever type you assigned in `DoWork`, and apply the data as needed to your UI controls.

```
worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
{
    ea.Result = GetMyData();
};

worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
{
    var myData = (myDataType)ea.Result;

    // Assign myData as needed to UI components...
};
```

Comment: I have hundreds of variables that need to be showed in UI and which are being calculated in DoWork. but using above method i can only show one variable on UI. Am i correct ?

Comment: @АндрейПро Just make GetMyData() return an object with all the required variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907.aspx) schedule your code to execute on UI thread and marshal necessary parameters. Try something like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Action<string>(() =>
    {
        // Access UI from here
    }),
    DispatcherPriority.Normal
);
```

Although this (or something like this, since this is notepad code) will solve your problem, you should consider using MVVM pattern in your implementation. Then you will be able to make changes to ViewModel (just update data) and UI will update accordingly.

Comment: You defeat the entire purpose of using a background worker if you just use Invoke.  The purpose of the BGW is that it handles the marshaling for you, as long as you use the appropriate events.

Comment: You also defeat purpose of data binding and thread pool by using a `BackgroundWorker` for WPF, but I tried to give quick solution to specific problem, and suggest better one if time permits person who asked to implement it.

Comment: He choose to use a BGW, he didn't choose to use data binding.  There's a difference between not using something entirely and mis-using something that you've chosen to use, with respect to data binding.  With respect to the thread pool, a single long running operation *shouldn't* be performed using the thread pool.  The thread pool is for a large number of short lived operations, so it would likely mis-using it if he did use the thread pool.